# Best way to split every nth string element and merge into array?

Tags: python, list

Sorry for the vague title, but it's hard to explain concisely.

Basically, imagine I have a list (in Python) that looks like this:

```
['a', 'b', 'c\nd', 'e', 'f\ng', 'h', 'i']
```

From that, I want to get this:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
```

One way I was thinking of doing this was using `reduce` like so:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x + y.split('\n'), lst, [])
```

But I don't think this is very efficient, since it doesn't take advantage of the fact that we know every nth element has the separator in it. Any suggestions?

Edit: for more background on how the array was constructed, which may the problem.

I have text in the form:

```
Ignorable line
Field name 1|Field name 2|Field name 3|Field name 4
Value 1|Value 2|Value 3|Value 4
Value 1|Value 2|Value 3|Value 4
...
```

Where we can have an arbitrary amount of field names, and there will always an equal number of values as field names on line. Note that we can have new lines in the values. We only know that the will be separated by a '|'. So we could have

```
Value 1|This is an long
value that extends over multiple
lines|Value 3|Value 4
```

How I currently do this is by doing a `s.split('\n', 2)` so that we get the field names in their own string, and the values in their own string. Then, when splitting the values by '|', we get the list of the form I originally mentioned.

Comment: what do you mean every nth element ... it looks like your n changes from 3 to 2 ... besides its probably plenty fast ... unless its actually not, but in that case you would know that that was your bottleneck .... premature optimization is the root of all evil

Comment: In the example the \n always follows the 3rd item (c is the 3rd letter of the alphabet; f is the 6th). I'm curious what's causing you to get the initial list in this format. Maybe the code would be cleaner if you changed how you construct the original list... this feels like a work-around for a broken parser.

Comment: @ramcdougal it may be that it's not the best way to construct that list. I'll update the post with how I got it in that form.

Comment: If you're starting with lines and lines in one string `s`, why not remove the newlines, then split at the vertical bars. Something like ``items=s.replace('\n', ' ').split('|')``

Comment: Did you mean `items=s.replace('\n', ' ').split('|') ? Because I did something along those lines and things were much faster. Thanks for that!

Comment: Are you sure that you really want a single list with all your values in it? If the Values in the different columns have different meanings, you'd probably be better off with either four lists, or with a list of 4-tuples.

Comment: The single list with all the values in it allows me to zip up slices of the list with the header names to create a dictionary from a list of tuples with the header name and value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just do `('\n'.join(lst)).split()` to get the 2nd list.

```
In [17]:

%timeit reduce(lambda x, y: x + y.split('\n'), lst, [])
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.64 µs per loop
In [18]:

%timeit ('\n'.join(lst)).split() 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.09 µs per loop
```

Thanks to @Joran Beasley for suggesting `split()` over `split('\n')`!

## Edit

Now I see your updated question, I think we can avoid getting into such a situation in the beginning, see (using `re`):

```
In [71]:

L=re.findall('([^|]+)\|',
           ''.join(['|'+item+'|' if item.count('|')==3 else item for item in S.split('\n')[1:]])+'|')
In [72]:

zip(*[L[i::4] for i in range(4)]) #4 being the number of fields.
Out[72]:
[('Field name 1', 'Field name 2', 'Field name 3', 'Field name 4'),
 ('Value 1', 'Value 2', 'Value 3', 'Value 4'),
 ('Value 1',
  'This is an longvalue that extends over multiplelines',
  'Value 3',
  'Value 4')]
```

Looks like a dataset for `SAS` initially, am I right?

Comment: That's definitely much faster, but there may be new lines in the other  elements as well (could be multiple, unknown amounts). I'll update the post with that information.

Comment: Get a chance to solve the problem? If not, see edit.

Comment: I did, but this would work as well. The output I'm parsing is actually the request of a WQL query, using the wmic utility on Linux. See http://www.aldeid.com/wiki/Wmic-linux

Answer (score 2):

premature optimization is the root of all evil

if you are actually experiencing performance issues because of this code thats one thing, but I doubt you are.

when you optimize you are often sacrificing readability what I would do if it was me

```
list(itertools.chain(*[item.split() for item in lst]))
```

which is very clear what your doing

Comment: Hi Joran, are you sure this is gonna work? I think it should be `list(itertools.chain(*[item.split() for item in lst]))`

Comment: ahh your totally right your answer is better in terms of clarity I think anyway ("although id probably just use a normal split without a delimiter but meh)